# Java for converting DAO to R2RML for RDF creation?

Tags: java, rdf, r2rml

Does anyone know of any programming techniques for converting a Java DAO objects(i.e. objects created from a database schema) to R2RML objects/files for RDF creation in graph databases*?

I am working with a non-standard database, and only have the DAOs and not the database.

Any help most appreciated.  Thanks.

**Similar questions which ask about libraries specifically (which I am told is a no-no, but people on SO get away with it anyway):*

[How can I easily convert RDF triples to/from an idomatic Java POJO business object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34098348/how-can-i-easily-convert-rdf-triples-to-from-an-idomatic-java-pojo-business-obje)

[Is there a Java open source implementation of R2RML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656998/is-there-a-java-open-source-implementation-of-r2rml)

Comment: Is the requirement to create R2RML, or to save the DAOs into the RDF database (or just generate RDF from them)?

Comment: R2RML is mapping from DB to RDF. Even if you would generate R2RML from DAOs how could you use the R2RML mapping on your "non-standard" DB? If it is possible to use them, you could have created them the "classic" way: i.e. not from DAO but from DB.

Comment: @Nathan Cox not necessarily so.  The non-standard DB that I am using to create DAO objects with uses constantly changing tables in the DB to create the DAO objects.  The DB may even change at some point, but the DAO objects will remain the same (or at least, mostly similar).  This is why I wish to focus on the DAO and not the DB for R2RML creation (and R2RML updates).